# A General Question on Powers of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

There is an example on positive matrices in Artin's algebra (page 113, $2^{nd}$ edition). The matrix is $A=\begin{bmatrix} 3&2\\ 1&4\end{bmatrix}$. The argument is that there must exist a positive eigen-vector for this matrix. Instead of using the standard way to show this claim, Artin argues that this matrix will send the first quadrant $S$ to itself. Therefore, we can get a nested inclusion statement like $\cdots\subset A^2S\subset AS\subset S$. Then it is intuitive to notice that the intersection of this sequence is either the smallest sector or simply a half line. By definition, it is not hard to see one eigen-vector of $A$ is $(1, 1)^T$ and alike. Alternatively, we could use limit argument to show that the limit of $A^nS$ is simply a line. In order to do this, we need to show that the limit of $A^ne_1$ and the limit of $A^ne_2$, where $e_i$ is the $i^{th}$ standard basis vector, are the same. However, it is not clear to me how to find these limits easily since the matrix $A$ is not of special pattern and its power is not easy to be expressed in some simple formula. However, I managed to do this in R as the following graph shows. [image: Numerical Results] Now, my question is whether there is a simple way to deal with powers of a general matrix so that we can consider its limiting behavior. One thing I can think of is to diagonalize a matrix by its eigen-basis. But in terms of the current question, we need eigen-vectors in the first place.

Comment: In general, by hand (or theoretically) you compute powers using diagonalization. However, using a computer to find eigenvectors by the power method (iterating as you're doing here) is a computational tool that's quite powerful.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking for.  Your question, as you've stated it, is "is there a simple way to deal with powers of a general matrix so that we can consider its limiting behavior". Do you mean to ask if there is a way to find a powers of a matrix other than by diagonalization?  Are you specifically concerned with positive matrices?  Also, note that not all matrices are diagonalizable, so in order to take the successive powers of a "general" matrix, you would have to use Jordan canonical form or something of the like.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for your response. You are right. I am wondering whether there is a way to deal with general matrices other than diagonalization. I am also aware that some matrices cannot be diagonalized and Jordan form may be used there. However, it is known that Jordan form can be rather ill conditioned in numerical procedures most of the time.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your response.

Comment: @XuS would you be interested in methods that apply, in particular, to matrices with positive entries?  At any rate, I think that Schur upper-triangularization (which can be implemented for arbitrary matrices) might be a good place to start looking.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I am not particularly concerned with positive matrices. Yes, you are right. Schur is a way to reveal eigenvalues. I also found the most widely used method is QR algorithm. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to characterize any power of a $2 \times 2$ matrix. Any $2 \times 2$ matrix satisfies its characteristic polynomial. Thus if 
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}a & b\cr c & d\end{pmatrix}$$
then its characteristic polynomial is 
$$ \Delta(t) = \det  \left(  \begin{pmatrix}a & b\cr c & d\end{pmatrix} \right)=
{t}^{2}-(a+t) \,t+a\,d-b\,c$$
Hence by Cayley-Hamilton theorem we have
$$ A^2 - (a+d) A + (a\,d-b\,c) I = 0$$ or
$$A^2  = \theta A + \mu I$$ where $\theta = (a+d)$, $\mu = -( a\,d-b\,c)$.
The above condition can be used to write any power of $A$ in terms of $A$ and $I$.

There are two ways to proceed:

Method 1: Divide $t^n$ by $\Delta(t)$ and let $R(t) = \alpha_n t + \beta_n$ be the reminder (easily obtained if we know the roots of $\Delta(t)$) Then 
$$
A^n = \alpha_n A + \beta_n I
$$

Method 2: This uses the same idea but uses recursion and induction. Let
$$
A^n = \alpha_n A + \beta_n I
$$
This is clearly valid for $n=0$ with $\alpha_0=0$, $\beta_0 = 1$.

The induction/recursion step is
$$
A^{n+1} = A\, A^n = \alpha_n A^2 + \beta_n A = \alpha_n (\theta A + \mu I) + \beta_n A
= (\beta_n +\alpha_n \theta) A + \alpha_n \mu I
$$
Hence the recursive formula is
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha_{n+1} &= \theta\, \alpha_n + \beta_n \\
\beta_{n+1} &= \mu \,\alpha_n
\end{align}
$$
To be honest, the second method coverts the problem to powers of a matrix with a special structure. The above condition can be written as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{n+1}\cr \beta_{n+1}\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}\theta & 1 \cr \mu & 0\end{pmatrix}  
\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{n}\cr \beta_{n}\end{pmatrix}  
$$
and hence
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{n}\cr \beta_{n}\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}\theta & 1 \cr \mu & 0\end{pmatrix} ^n  
\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{0}\cr \beta_{0}\end{pmatrix}  
$$